# Is the phrase "Icy slush" redundant?

Tags: phrases

It's winter here in New York, and my driveway was a sheet of ice yesterday. Today, the ice is softer, and a bit slushier.

Is it an icy slush? or a slush that is icy? Or just a slush, indicating that a slush is composed of ice and water?

Comment: Yes, it's a hair redundant, but it's still a meaningful term.  There is no requirement that every sentence you speak be subjected to scientific analysis and mathematical reduction.

Comment: Slush that turned icy. Snow is either powdery micro ice or micro ice flakes, which then becomes slushy--micro-ice/slush after some time. Or as soon as it hits the ground at warmer temperatures. Which would then get frozen when temperatures fall at night, either into hard macro-ice, or macro-icy slushy--micro-ice.

Comment: Or *slushy ice*.

Comment: @bib Just don’t forget that last word and confuse it with a _slushy_. I suspect whatever would be in it from a New York driveway would not exactly be good for you.

Comment: We just call it *slush*. *the snow has turned to slush*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet We NYers are tough. We drink stranger (and stronger) stuff than that.

Comment: We call it a lot of things.

Comment: Icy slurry is a particular meaning of *slush*, which does not always refer to the icy mix. So "icy slush" isn't redundant.

Comment: The word is *phrase*! Why does *phraise* make me think of strawberries...

Comment: @Mari-LouA À cause des _fraises_, peut-être. ;-)

Comment: Is the slush _itself_ icy, or is it on top of a persistent layer of ice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Wet rain* or *wet puddles* would be redundant terms, since what is rain or a puddle but wet?

Slush, on the other hand, isn't as absolute a term.  You could have some very heavy snow (*wet snow*), which isn't at all redundant, and is one type of slush.  *Icy slush* would be a different type, being more ice than water.

More to the point, whenever I refer to "icy slush," I'm actually referring to the likelihood of ice being *underneath* it, as in:

> The roads are very slippery due to a layer of icy slush.  Drive carefully.

Comment: bang on, to the point. +1

Answer (score 4):

In the same way that an orange that is more red than yellow could be called *reddish-orange*, it is perfectly acceptable to call slush that is more solid than liquid ***icy slush***.

Comment: perfectly phrased.